# Custom HTTP Headers with old proxies

Tags: http, proxy, http-headers

Is it true that some old proxies/caches will not honor some custom HTTP headers? If so, can you prove it with sections from the HTTP spec or some other information online?

I'm designing a REST API interface. For versioning I'm debating whether to use version as a part of the URL like (/path1/path2/v1 OR /path1/path2?ver=1) OR to use a custom Accepts X-Version header.

Comment: What do you mean by "honor"? I suspect you mean "pass through" but that's not really a complete question either, because you are probably also worried about whether the proxy would serve a previously cached response for which the second request had a different X-Version header. (That's permitted, if you're wondering.)

Comment: Yes I meant Pass-through. Also if I make sure my ETags hash on the X-Version header, then can I assume that the proxy will call the server with a If None Match and hence get a 200 for a different X-Version?

Answer (score -1):

I was just reading in O'Reilly's [Even Faster Websites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522315/) about how mainly internet security software, but really anything that has to check the contents of a page, might filter the Accept-Encoding header in order to reduce the CPU time used decompressing and reading the file. The books cites that about 15% of user have this issue.

However, I see no reason why other, custom headers would be filtered. On the other hand, there also isn't really any reason to send it as a header and not with GET is there? It's not really part of the HTTP protocol, it's just your API.

Edit: Also, see [the actual section of the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=E7p-07kNfXYC&lpg=PA122&dq=even%20faster%20websites&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q&f=false) I mention.